# Regular expression not working properly.in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, knockout.js

I am using the following code:

```
this.totalCars = kb.observable(model, 'totalCars').extend({required:true,min:1, max: 7,
       pattern : {
              params: /^[\d]*$/,
              message: 'Enter Valid Integer Number'              
          }
        });
```

and in the UI am using:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
     <input required
           type="number" 
           id="numberofcars" 
           title="Number of cars" 
           placeholder="Number of cars Offered" 
           autocomplete="off" 
           data-bind="value: totalCars"  
           min="1" maxlength="1" 
           class="form-control c-square c-theme input-sm">
</div>
```

It's accepting + and e,E

Note: it doesn't accept e+E characters. how to restrict here

Comment: This regex already does it, look https://regex101.com/r/xO6mM2/1

Comment: Try `params: '^[0-9]*$',`. BTW, is it `kb.observable` or `ko.observable`?

Comment: Just a note: if you want just `\d` you do not need to use `[]`... `^\d*$` is enough.

Comment: still it accepting + eE
without entering any numbers ,enter those characters its acceptig in chrome browser

Comment: in chrome its accepting +eE but in firefox its accepting all the characters.How to solve this issue...

Comment: Try setting the keyup event in the data-bind: `data-bind="value: totalCars, valueUpdate: 'keyup'"`. Also, use `type="text" `

Answer (score 1):

I suggest replacing your custom regex with the built in / [native rule](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Native-Rules) for numbers using `number: true`:

```js
var model = null;

var vm = {
  totalCars: ko.observable(model, 'totalCars').extend({
    required: true,
    min: 1,
    max: 7,
    number: true
  })
};

vm.errors = ko.validation.group(vm);

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout-validation/2.0.3/knockout.validation.min.js"></script>

<input required
       type="number"
       placeholder="Number of cars Offered" 
       data-bind="textInput: totalCars"  
       min="1" 
       maxlength="1" >
<hr>
Debug info: <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></pre>
```

PS. I also did something similar to what commenters suggested, using the `textInput` binding that makes sure the changes are pushed to the view model on key presses, not on blurring the input field. But that's just a minor change to make the example clearer.

[The relevant source from ko-validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/blob/v2.1.0/src/rules.js#L221) has this implementation for that native rule (slightly reformatted for SO legibility):

```
return ko.validation.utils.isEmptyVal(value) 
    || (validate && /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)?(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(value));
```

As you can see this regex is quite elaborate, and probably well-tested. It works [as I expected](https://regex101.com/r/tV8jQ0/1) at any rate.